# Silverstripe 4 - How to query for getting all data from table and add field to cmsField

Tags: php, regex, database, silverstripe

I want to gat all data From `Devmac_Product` Table and pass as a Object to show in cms

```
$getCat = "SELECT * FROM Devmac_Product WHERE ProductCategory REGEXP '(32)'";
$objResult = DB::query($getCat);

$f->addFieldToTab(
        'Root.Main',
        GridField::create(
            'Product',
            'Product List',
            $objResult,  // pass $objResult here
            GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
        )
        ->setRightTitle('Editing these products also effects the master list')
    );
```

Comment: Do you want to get all categories with a "32" in their IDs? Or why do you need a regex for this query? I don't understand what you're trying to acchieve - maybe there is an even simpler solution for your problem.

Comment: I want to get all product from the table where ProductCategoty data match with the given id. ProductCategory = ["28","32"]. 28, 32 is the page ids.

Comment: If "matchtes" means "equals", then you get all Products of cateogory 28 and 32 with this construct: `Product::get()->filter(['ProductCategory.ID' => [28,32])` This gets all products that are either in category 28 or in category 32.

Answer (score 1):

**Silverstripe 4** provides the best solution for that i.e

**filter** with its subclass **PartialMatch**. Here **Product** is the class and **32** is any number. Reff:https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/

Replace **$objResult** with this below **statemen**t

```
Product::get()->filter(array('ProductCategory:PartialMatch' => '32'));
```